# Get Rid Of App Switcher Tip Prompt In Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-8.1, virtual-machine, modern-ui, vmware-player

[image]

Running Windows 8.1 in a VMware Player virtual machine, and after launching a metro app I got this irritating tip:

> Swipe in from the edge to go back to the last app you were using.

Since I'm using a virtual machine, with a guest that doesn't require tools for in/out mouse hopping, I cannot swipe. This is one of those demonstrate you understand to get rid of type tips. Clicking won't make it go away, it wants you to demonstrate the instructions.

How can I get rid of this popup tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The solution is to go up to the top left corner of the screen. This will make the prompt disappear, and show you
the applist.

Answer (score 1):

You can also [disable them completely](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/31098-help-tips-enable-disable-windows-8-1-a.html) by running `regedit.exe`, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows`, create a key named `EdgeUI` and create a new 32Bit DWORD `DisableHelpSticker` and set this value to 1.